# Random vectors definitions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Billingsley writes in his book "Probability and measure":

[image]

This should mean that there are two ways to think of a random vector. Let [n] = {1,2,...,n}, then we can think of the random vector as a function belonging to  $\Omega \to ([n] \to \mathbb{R})$ or  belonging to $[n]\to (\Omega \to \mathbb{R})$. In some cases one definition works better. For example: if $X\in [2]\to(\Omega\to \mathbb{R})$, then one may define $X(1)\sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.5)$, $X(2)\sim\text{Normal(0,1)}$ and $\{X(1), X(2)\}$ is independent. It is less clear to me how to write the assumptions in the example if  $X\in \Omega\to([2]\to \mathbb{R})$.

Do you prefer one definition over the other, why?

EDIT:

Here are some clarifications about my notation.
If $x\in [n]\to \mathbb{R}$, then $x$ is an $n$-tuple. For example, a member of $[2]\to \mathbb{R}$, is x = (1,0), which is equivalent to x(1) = 1 and x(2) = 0. Similarly, a random variable X belonging to $\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If I write $X\in[2]\to(\Omega \to \mathbb{R})$, then X is a function from $i\in\{1,2\}$ to a function $X(i)\in \Omega \to\mathbb{R}$, which may be a random variable if $X(i)$ is measurable.

Comment: The definition in the picture is clear. In your notation, what do you mean by "$\Omega\to([n]\to \mathbb{R})$"?

Comment: I mean $\Omega\to([n]\to \mathbb{R})= (\mathbb{R}^{[n]})^\Omega$, which is the set of functions from $\Omega$ to $n$-tuples.

Comment: Billingsley defined what is a measurable mapping. You are worried with the probability law of X. I believe that the problem is that you tried to define the probability distribution of X by its marginal distributions. In general, this is not possible.

Comment: Thank you Celine. I have tried to add a clarification. Please let me know if I am still unclear.

Comment: About the measurability, we already know that $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ measurable iff each $X_i$ is measurable (both are equivalent, and so, none is better than the other). My point was that $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ has a distribution function $P_X$. But $P_X$ defines uniquely the distribution of each $X_i$. On the other hand, you considered random variables $X_1, X_2$ with certain distributions $P_{X_1}, P_{X_2}$, and couldn't define $P_{X_1,X_2}$. In general, you won't find it. All you know is that $X$ is measurable. Yes, it was clear to me.